# Comparing String type input to MediaPlayer type (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I Need your help!

I have this:

```
public static String var = "s_c";
```

and this:

```
MediaPlayer suono_c = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.s_c);
```

and i need something like this:

```
if (var == suono_c) { ......and so on
```

but in Java I can't compare a String type var with a MediaPlayer type...
What's the best solution?

Thanks for your help!